# Moving Yii2 Admin to Extensions Folder

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

I have the need to move the Yii2-admin module to extensions folder from vendor folder. So my module is now extensions/mdmsoft.

In my config directory I add the alias

```php
'mdmsoft/yii2-admin' =>
    array(
        'name'    => 'mdmsoft/yii2-admin',
        'version' => '1.0.4.0',
        'alias'   =>
            array(
                '@mdm/admin' => $extensionDir . '/mdmsoft/yii2-admin',
            ),
    ),
```

Where `$extensionDir` points to the extensions folder.
I have done similar thing to other modules like yii2 user module and it works perfectly.

However in this case it doesn't work. I get the error

> "Class mdm\admin\components\AccessControl does not exist"

It works well when it is in the vendor folder. But I need to move it to extensions folder to make some changes.

Answer (score 2):

Moving things out of *vendor* dir can brake the class autoloader, which is made to work with composer. If you need to make changes to any composer based extension it's best to make a fork of it and add your fork to *composer.json*.

You don't even have to publish your version on packagist.org, you can add your repo in the **repositories** section of *composer.json*.